# Scaled cumulative abnormal returns - Event study

Tags: least-squares, prediction, finance

In my event study I use an OLS time-series regression. $y_t$ is the dependent variable on day $t$. $x_t$ is the explanatory variable on day $t$. This regression uses observations during the so-called estimation period which precedes the event window:

(1) $y_t=\alpha + \beta x_t + u_t$

(or in matrix notation $y=Xb+u$)

To compute prediction errors during the event window $e_t$ for day $t$ of my event window (which follows the estimation period) I use $\alpha$ and $\beta$ estimated from the previous equation (1).

(2) $e_t=y_t- \alpha - \beta x_t $

Scaling them ($e_t$) by their forecast-corrected standard deviation yields scaled prediction errors $e_t^{scaled}$ for day $t$ with $s$ as the standard deviation of the residuals ($u_t$) estimated during the estimation period (eq. 1) and $\sqrt{1+d}$ as the forecast correction of the standard deviation $s$:

(3) $e_{t}^{scaled}=\frac{e_{t}}{s\sqrt{1+d_t}}$

(4) $d=x_t^{'}(X^{'}X)^{-1}x_t$

$x_t^{'}$ is a vector containing the values of the explanatory variables on event day $t$ and $X$ is a matrix containing the values of the explanatory variables during the estimation period (see eq. 1).

I would like to calculate scaled **cumulative** prediction errors $ce_{t_0,t_1}^{scaled}$ with the **regular** cumulative prediction error defined as $ce_{t_0,t_1}=\sum_{t=t_0}^{t_1}e_t$. $t_0$ indicates the first prediction error (on day $t_0$) used in the sum and $t_1$ the last one.

Can I calculate $ce_{t_0,t_1}^{scaled}$ as $ce_{t_0,t_1}^{scaled}=ce_{t_0}^{scaled}+ce_{t_1}^{scaled}$? As far as I understood from Kolari and Pynnönen's "Event study testing with cross-sectional correlation of abnormal returns" this should be working out but I am not very sure.

Thank you all and sorry for the long post :)

Comment: I am not familiar with your notation and I think that is probably true for many other of our members who might like to answer your question.

Comment: I tried to use the notation of the relevant literature in financial economics. I am sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I changed the notation to generalize my question.